# How are binary values assigned to new symbols?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, binary, ascii

Currently in computer science, when we enter data (such as a letter, number, symbol, etc.), it gets converted to binary and stored on a machine. Thus all 8-bit binary numbers up to 255 have been allocated with some predefined value.

My question is: What happens if some new symbol has been generated and I want to store it or represent it on a machine? How is this binary number is allocated?

Comment: See [Proposed New Characters](https://www.unicode.org/faq/prop_new_characters.html). Also, note that your current understanding 30-50 years old. So, it's good that you are questioning it.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if some new symbol has been generated

This depends on who generated the symbol (ITYM character). You as an end user are only allowed to allocate/pick a number (code point) from a [private use area](http://enwp.org/Private_Use_Areas), [see an example](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.unicode/2012/02/msg3347.html).

If you require interoperability, you need to [submit the characters to the Unicode consortium](https://unicode.org/pending).

Answer (score 0):

#### Unicode

This happens all of the time with character allocation in [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). For example, characters were added in Unicode v12.0 in April of 2019, including yawning face,  (code point 1F971), guide dog (code point 1F9AE), , and yo-yo  (code point 1FA80). Depending on your browser and OS versions, you may or may not see these as emoji.

The most common encoding scheme used on the internet is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is one of several Unicode encodings.

#### ASCII

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), as an encoding, is 7-bit and covers values 0-127. If you try to decode a character outside of that range as ASCII, the error will depend on the implementation. For example, 'A' is in both ASCII (7-bit) and [LATIN1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (8-bit) while '¡' is only in LATIN1. In python, this will generate an error:

```py
# script.py
import binascii

def encode_binary(input, encoding):
    return bin(int.from_bytes(input.encode(encoding), 'big'))

print(encode_binary('A', 'utf8'))
print(encode_binary('A', 'latin1')) 
print(encode_binary('A', 'ascii')) 
print() # print a newline
print(encode_binary('¡', 'utf8'))
print(encode_binary('¡', 'latin1')) 
print(encode_binary('¡', 'ascii'))
--------

$ python script.py
0b1000001
0b1000001
0b1000001

0b1100001010100001
0b10100001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u00a1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about encoding and decoding (semantic/symbol to/from a code/number).

The question is too generic. It depends on the encoding method. Some are complete, so there is not place to extend for new symbols (e.g. ASCII). Some foresaw methods enhance and complete (e.g. Unicode), to a certain extend.

Sometime the "enhancement" is done at an other level: it is common to have ASCII and then escape sequences or codes (html: `&#x24B8;` or `&copy;` Note: two different symbols, also the same/similar *symbol* may have different encoding; or also ASCII escape sequences by switching code point plane/font). Sometime just as makeup language, e.g. `\copyright`.

So there are many way. Just I hope people will think at beginning about enhancement, and implement standards/conventions/protocols in a way that they can be extended.